# PHP - выбрать из файла через preg_match или preg_grep

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть файл, читаю его через

```
$lines = file($file);
```

В нем следующая структура:

```
[/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]

Mode=false
Class=Pattern
DirectoryName=/123/124
Pattern=.*
Refresh=true
```

Нужно выбрать только  `[/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]` и `DirectoryName = /123/124`

Через `preg_match` или `preg_grep` не могу задать, чтобы рассматривались все строки как одна (аналог `/(\[.*\]).*(DirectoryName)/s`)

Comment: А не пробовали [`parse_ini_file`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-ini-file.php)? Регулярные выражения, в основном, сделаны для работы с простым текстом.

Comment: Не пробовал. Попробую сейчас. Вот уже с ним поинтересней. Сейчас дальше попробую развить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, Вы читаете файл через функцию `file`, и содержимое помещается в массив, но если вы хотите получить не массивом, то можно использовать функцию `file_get_contents`, после чего можно использовать `preg_match_all` для поиска нужных вам данных.

***#1*** Пример с `file_get_contents`:

```
preg_match_all('~\[.*?\]|DirectoryName=.*?\s~', file_get_contents($file), $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]
    [1] => DirectoryName=/123/124
)
```

***#2*** Пример с `file`, лично у меня никак проблем не было найти нужные строки:

```
$matches = preg_grep('~\[[^]]*\]|DirectoryName=(.*?)~', $lines);
print_r($matches);
```

Получаем:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]
    [4] => DirectoryName=/123/124
)
```

---

***#3, upd:*** еще один вариант, слегка велосипед, но все же работает, хд

Имеем данные сразу нескольких конфигов, в одном из трех отсутствует `DirectoryName`

(в моем случае у меня все необходимое находится в переменной `$string`, но в вашем случае подключаете из файла через: `$string = file_get_contents($file);`

И так, рассмотрим:

```
$string = '
    [/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]

    Mode=false
    Class=Pattern
    DirectoryName=/123/124
    Pattern=.*
    Refresh=true

    [/dep/1337]

    Mode=false
    Class=Pattern
    Pattern=.*
    Refresh=true

    [/dep/File]

    Mode=false
    Class=Pattern
    DirectoryName=test_name
    Pattern=.*
    Refresh=true
';
```

Далее делаем фильтрацию путем избавления от тех конфигов, в которых нет `DirectoryName`:

```
$exp = array_filter(explode('[', $string));
$tmp = '';

foreach ($exp as $value) {
    $tmp .= (substr_count($value, 'DirectoryName') > 0) ? '['.($value) : null;
}
```

А далее действуем по первому примеру:

```
preg_match_all('~\[.*?\]|DirectoryName=.*?\s~', $tmp, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Получаем нужный нам результат:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]
    [1] => DirectoryName=/123/124
    [2] => [/dep/File]
    [3] => DirectoryName=test_name
)
```

[`Демо`](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/0e8d609bcda17530556febee5665257316c620da) последнего примера.

Comment: Я не точно сформулировал. Извиняюсь. Мне нужно рассматривать этот блок от начала квадратных скобок и до следующего блока с открывабщейся квадратной скобкой как одно целое. Иначе по этой регулярке мы цепляет и те строки внутри блоков, в которых нет DirectoryName.

Comment: То есть в файле у вас несколько подобных структур?

Comment: Да все верно. Как раз на этом я и споткнулся. Что может идти блок, который не содержит DirectoryName и мы захватываем по условию ИЛИ как раз такие без DirectoryName . Например такой:

[/dep/1233/TRANS_UPD/En/Record/Stream/File]

Mode=false
Class=Pattern
Pattern=.*
Refresh=true

Comment: @DimaKuzmin, обновил решение. добавил еще один вариант, рассмотрите его